# recover deleted resource folder

Tags: xcode

I accidentally deleted the resource folder of my project. Is there a way to recover that?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't empty the Trash yet, you can grab it from the Trash and re-add it to the project.

Comment: I dont see it in trash. If I remeber correctly I selected delete reference when prompted. Did not select also move to trash

Comment: If you deleted the reference only, then the folder isn't deleted, it's just removed from the project. Re-add the reference by going to Project -> Add to Project... and selecting the folder.